# Docker - all-spark-notebook Communications link failure

Tags: docker, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-server

I'm new using docker and spark.

My docker-compose.yml file is

```
volumes:
  shared-workspace:
services:
  notebook:
    image: docker.io/jupyter/all-spark-notebook:latest
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-jupyter-jars
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
    volumes:
      - shared-workspace:/opt/workspace
```

And the Dockerfile-jupyter-jars is:

```
FROM docker.io/jupyter/all-spark-notebook:latest
USER root
RUN wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.28/mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar
RUN mv mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar /usr/local/spark/jars/
USER jovyan
```

To it start up a run

```
docker-compose up --build
```

The server is up and running and I'm interested to use spark-sql, but it is throwing and error trying to connect to mysql server:
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
[image]

I can see the mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar in the "jars" folder, and I have used same sql instruction in apache spark non docker version and it works.

Mysql db server is also reachable from the same server I'm running the Docker.
[image]

Do I need to enable something to reach external connections? Any idea?

Reference: https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/all-spark-notebook

Comment: You don't need to specify the image _and_ the Dockerfile in your docker-compose.yaml.  Try once just specifying the image and see if it works?  If it is a custom image, please remove `image` from docker-compose (ie., just specify the Dockerfile), declare the ports in the Dockerfile and try once?

Comment: I have removed image from docker-compose.yml file, the ports 8888 seems fine because I'm able to access jupyter notebook. But still same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile-jupyter-jars files were correct, since I was using mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar it requires a SSL or to disable explicitly.

```
jdbc:mysql://user:password@xx.xx.xx.xx:3306/inventory?useSSL=FALSE&amp;nullCatalogMeansCurrent=true
```

I'm going to left this example for: Docker - all-spark-notebook with MySQL dataset